# Is my solution to this SQL query correct?

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database, relation

In my exam we were given the following relations:

```
COURSES(**Number**, School, CourseName)

STUDENTS(**SNumber**, Surname, FirstName, School)

EXAMS(**Student**, **Course**, Grade, Date)
```

where the keys are in bold.  The EXAMS relation stores information of students that passed an exam for a given course .EXAMS.Student references STUDENTS.SNumber and EXAMS.Course references COURSES.Number.

We wear asked to write one SQL query that retrieves all the following information for each student number:

-their surname

-how many different exams they passed

-how many different grades they obtained

-the minimum, average and maximum grade they obtained in their exams."

Firstly, I included in my answer that I noticed that, as EXAMS only stores information about a student who passed an exam, there is no way to know if a student failed an exam and so we could only count how many different *pass* grades they obtained. Here is the query I wrote:

```
SELECT S.SNumber, S.Surame,
       COUNT(E.Student) AS NumberOfExamsPassed,
       COUNT(DISTINCT E.Grade) AS NumberOfDifferentPassGrades,
       MIN(E.Grade) AS MinimumGrade,
       MAX(E.Grade) AS MaximumGrade,
       AVG(E.Grade) AS AverageGrade
FROM Students S, EXAMS E
GROUP BY E.Student;
```

Would this be a sufficient solution?

Comment: You should `join` your tables, preferably using `select * from x [left|inner|right] join y on x.id = y.id` syntax. I'm not sure what the result is from your current query, but I would expect a cartesian product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Explicit Joins.

```
SELECT S.SNumber, S.Surame,
       COUNT(E.Student) AS NumberOfExamsPassed,
       COUNT(DISTINCT E.Grade) AS NumberOfDifferentPassGrades,
       MIN(E.Grade) AS MinimumGrade,
       MAX(E.Grade) AS MaximumGrade,
       AVG(E.Grade) AS AverageGrade
FROM Students S
INNER JOIN EXAMS E ON S.SNumber = E.Student
GROUP BY E.Student;
```

Comment: Yes, that certainly makes sense. A join is definitely needed between the two relations, I don't know how I missed that in the exam.